# Copiar elementos de un ArrayList

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de copiar cada elemento de un ArrayList n veces en el mismo array, es decir, tengo el siguiente array:
[Hola, Mundo]
Y suponiendo que n es igual a 4 el resultado seria el siguiente:
[Hola, Hola, Hola, Hola, Mundo, Mundo, Mundo, Mundo]
Pero si n menor o igual a 0 entonces tendría que eliminar todo el contenido del array
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```java
public class Prueba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ar = {"how", "are", "you?"};
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ar));

        stutter(lista, 4);

        System.out.println(lista);
    }

    public static void stutter (List<String> list, int k) {
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        if (k <= 0) {
            int cont = 0;

            while (cont < 2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    list.remove(i);
                }
                cont++;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size();) {
                copiar(lista, k, list.get(i));
            }
        }

        list = lista;
    }

    public static void copiar(List<String> lista, int k, String s){
        int cont = 0;

        while (cont < k) {            
            lista.add(s);
            cont++;
        }
    }

    //[how, how, how, how, are, are, are, are, you?, you?, you?, you?]
}
```

En el método stutter lo que hago es crear un nuevo arraylist y luego compruebo si n es menor o igual a 0 para eliminar todo el contenido del array y si no uso un bucle para recorrer el array y, usando el metodo copiar, copio n veces cada elemento del array en el nuevo array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errores en el método stutter:

```
public static void stutter (List<String> list, int k) {
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        if (k <= 0) {
            int cont = 0;

            while (cont < 2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    list.remove(i);
                }
                cont++;
            }
        } else {
           // error 1: faltaba el incremento de la variable i (i++)
           // eso provoca un loop infinito
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++) { 
                copiar(lista, k, list.get(i));
            }
        }

        // error 2: lista tiene una referencia a un nuevo objeto 
        // por eso al asignarlo a list no actualiza los valores
        // list = lista;

        // lo correcto sería, limpiar la lista : list.clear() 
        // y agregar los valores list.addAll(lista);
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(lista);
    }
```

Te agrego una solución más simple:

```
public static void stutter (List<String> list, int k) {

            // si k <= 0 limpiar la lista y retornar
            if(k <= 0) {
                list.clear();
                return;
            }

            // crear nueva lista
            List<String> nuevaLista = new ArrayList<>();

            // recorrer  la lista original
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                // iterar las veces que indique k
                for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                    // agregar el valor de list en la posición i las veces que indique k
                    nuevaLista.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }
            // limpiar la lista original
            list.clear();
            // agregar los  valores de nuevaLista en la lista original
            list.addAll(nuevaLista);
        }
```